Using Nuget packages for WPF when running as plug-in
I have a problem with loading external resources into a WPF application. The WPF app should run as a plugin for a 3rd party program. I believe it is irrelevant which program it is, but in this case it is about Autodesk Inventor.
My project structure is as follows;

One WPF class library
One testing app, which is a WPF application which just shows the main window and hooks into the process so for developing I can test without restarting Inventor the whole time.
One plug-in class library, this gets loaded by the program.

Basically the test-app and the plug-in setup code are identical. Only in the plug-in there is some logic that hooks the main window to a control in the inventor interface.
Everything works fine as long as I don't use any external packages. I want to use some packages to make my life easier. But as soon as I use some control from example MahApps, and I run the plug-in project, I get a FileNotFound exception for the package DLL. The DLL is present in the output directory though.

Because my wpf class library does not have an app.xaml, I am importing the resources in the MainWindow.
Initialization code:
    public void InitializePropertyEditor()
{
    AppHost = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            PropertyEditorServices.ConfigureServices(hostContext, services);
        })
        .Build();

    AppHost.Services.AddViewModelLocator();
    AppHost.Start();
    
    // create window
    var mainWindow = AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService<MainWindow>();
    mainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    mainWindow.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
    mainWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    
    var helper = new WindowInteropHelper(mainWindow);
    helper.EnsureHandle();
    var hwnd = helper.Handle;

    propertyWindow = GetDockableWindow();
    propertyWindow.DisabledDockingStates = DockingStateEnum.kDockBottom | DockingStateEnum.kDockTop;

    propertyWindow.AddChild(hwnd);
    HwndSource.FromHwnd(hwnd)?.AddHook(WndProc);

    // perform initialization
    var initService = AppHost.Services.GetRequiredService<IInitializationService>();
    initService.Initialize();
}

I really have no clue why it will not work. Any ideas?

I'm afraid you will need to find all dependencies (dlls etc) that mahApps have and change their type to be embedded in your app, then you will need to retrieve those dlls in code and loaded them into your assembly. Have a look at this question

Thanks, will try that. But how come this only occurs when running from Inventor/a 3rd party program? The project reference is the same, the way of starting the application is the same.

It's really simple, when you ship/load your plugin, it's running directory is different than when running in Visual Studio, I am guessing that if you manually copy the mah apps files into the directory where autodesk is, then it should work. All it is, you are running the app where dependent assemblies are not present. The same will happen if you remove them from debug folder

But I am copying the entire build (debug) folder to another folder, where Autodesk can read it. And why does the problem only happen with packages that are loaded in XAML? I mean I am using more packages, those are fine. Also the MahApps.Metro.dll is actually in that folder. It seems like just the XAML loader is looking in the wrong directory.

That would be down to how Autodesk works, which is out of my depth.

I still doubt that the problem is purely caused by Autodesk. I will try the suggestion from the first post when I return from holiday and do a test with another program.
